# Set default value to Opportunity Stage filed in 'Edit Dependencies' popup

Tags: lightning, opportunity, salespath

I have opportunity record. And when click on 'Mark Stage as Complete' button 'Edit Dependencies' popup comes in lightning opportunity path.
How to set default value to 'Stage' picklist field.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot set default value for Stage field on opportunity.

Kindly review [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HYUq) and vote for this feature.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how value 'Closed Won - PA' has been set by default for stage field when click 'Mark stage as complete button'.

Comment: When you click on 'Mark Stage' button then it will pick next available picklist lov. For eg., If the current status on opp record is ''Closed Won - AA" and it will populate next lov which is "'Closed Won - PA".